# Changing "targeted runtime" for multiple projects

Tags: eclipse

I have a workspace with several hundreds of projects that I imported, all of them have (thru the imported eclipse setting files) targeted runtime set to some non-existent server that probably used to be on the computer of the person who wrote those projects.

How can I change the targeted runtime in all those projects in one operation, without repeating it hundreds of times?

I could only see how I do it for one project at a time (right click project > properties > targeted runtimes).

Comment: Just find in which exactly of the eclipse file is this stored and then do `sed` and regex replacement in all of them. Candidates are `.classpath`, `.project` and the files in `.settings` folder.